# GCM 'Not Registered' Error

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

So yes I have done my research and none of the resources I found had an answer that was correct.

I have enabled GCM in my api console on google. I have put the sender ID in my app and the server key in the server. When I run my server to send notifications through gcm I get an error 'Not Registered'. I get the device key with this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push.

How come I keep getting the not registered error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this post. The answer for anyone using this plugin who keeps getting an error like me. Try using this inside your app folder: cordova plugin rm phonegap-plugin-push and then reinstall it with your sender_id again

Answer (score 2):

you have to use FCM it's now essay to use and better than GCM
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client
 for node js coding this link should help https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm

Answer (score 1):

Do you get token in your app(client)?
When server send push message, server need server_api_key and token.

1. Client register in GCM. (It get token)
2. Server send message (token and server_api_key)

If client do not register, you get message "Not registered"